# how to add a text label next to the x-axis dates in a chart using the D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js for charting and im trying to add a label next to teh dates. Below if how the dates on the x axis look:

[image]

I'm tryign to add the label in front of the dates:

```
Week Jun 21 12:00Am  Jun 22 12:00AM and so on...(shown above)
```

Here is what i tried:Js

```
   var margin = {top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 60, left:120},
   w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
   h = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
   var lines= d3.select('.graph');
   lines.enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", w / 2 )
        .attr("y",  h + margin.bottom)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Week");
```

But didnt work for me. any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: This won't work because you didn't do any [data binding](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) and hence will have an empty `enter()` selection. There is no need to specify `enter()` if you want to append just one label. You could just `d3.select()` the element you want your text appended to and call `.append()` directly on that one. If you need more help with that, please provide more code or a working JSFiddle to play around with.